# Can't access my websites from my IP in different operating systems

Tags: windows-10, ip, firewall, wordpress, shared-hosting

I use my internet connection via a typically installed Win10 home / Apple Iphone (iOS) with different browsers. The operating systems and browsers are all up to date.

I host two WordPress websites on a CentOS shared-server environment at siteground.com.

### My problem

When surfing from **my IP** I get the error "site can’t be reached", from all browsers. It doesn't matter if it's WIFI or Ethernet, I'm still having the above problem.

The sites work fine and are fully accessible from other IP addresses though (for example, if I change my WIFI to a free WIFI found by my PC, I can access the sites).

### Debug tries

After using Windows troubleshooting tool in Chrome after navigating to a relevant domains, I got this error:

> Windows Could not Automatically Detect Network’s Proxy Settings.

#### Powershell

`ping TARGET_DOMAIN` brings:

> Reply from TARGET_IP: bytes=32 time=189ms TTL=53

`tracert TARGET_DOMAIN` brings:

> Unable to resolve target system name TARGET_DOMAIN.

Also, `nslookup TARGET_DOMAIN` brings:

```
nslookup : *** Request to Broadcom.Home timed-out At line:1 char:1
+ nslookup TARGET_DOMAIN
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (*** Request to Broadcom.Home timed-out:String) [], RemoteException
```

### Solution tries

Flushing my local DNS cache in Powershell with `ipconfig /flushdns`, then flushing my browser's cache, doesn't help (not even after turning off [WPAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol)).

### Further details

- I didn't touch the Windows HOSTS file.
- As of the moment, and just for testing, no security plugin (like WordFence or Loginizer) is installed on any website so the problem shouldn't come from WordPress.
- The hosting company couldn't track any problem in the server environment; a talented sysadmin of their team, told me that the problem is of my end.

### My question

What may be the problem?

Comment: The problem might be with your ISP. Try : (1) Set your DNS server to [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), setting your DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. (2) Do the same to your router. (3) Try to connect through some free VPN for testing.

Comment: Point (1) is described by Google in the section [Change your DNS servers settings](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). Point (2) is very similar but done from your router control panel after login. For point (3) you can pick a free VPN from [this article](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-vpn.htm) with reviews.

Comment: It seems like everybody has jumped upon my suggestions. 200 reps causes a feeding frenzy.

Comment: If you let me know the router's model I can help you with instructions.

Comment: @harrymc It's D-LINK DSL G256DG.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I assume it can be a nightmare to be forwarded to a DNS engineer in this company. Service in many Israeli companies is usually insanely unprofessional at least when mostly given between citizens of this country. I can sacrifice not going to the root cause in this case, if a workaround (or a solution of using other DNS server) is good enough.

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are getting these problems only when trying to access this website
while using the ISP, the problem is not with your computers or phones.

The problem has to be with your ISP, either his router or his DNS server.
It might even be that the ISP has erroneously flagged this website as
serving malware and is blocking it actively.
The three steps below will help you diagnose whether this is indeed the case
and will help find a workaround.

**Step 1 : Use the Google DNS servers for your PC**

The first step is to use your ISP but bypass his DNS server.
You do that by setting your DNS server to
[Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/),
whose addresses are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.
Note down the previous DNS settings as before the change.
The following Google article describes the method in the section
[Change your DNS servers settings](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

If this works, then to apply it to all your devices continue to the following
Step 2, but skip Step 3. If it does not work, go directly to Step 3.

**Step 2 : Set your router to use the Google DNS servers**

Login to your router and access the DNS page by clicking on the
*Advanced* menu link at the top, and then click the *DNS* menu link on the left.

Assuming your router is connected by cable, select
*Use the following Static DNS IP address* and enter 8.8.8.8 in the first box
and 8.8.4.4 in the second. Terminate by clicking Apply/Save.

Test accessing the problem website from another computer/phone,
and if it works then undo the changes you did to your computer in Step 1
as they are no longer required, and don't go to Step 3.

[image]

**Step 3 : Connect your PC via VPN**

Here we test if your ISP is actively blocking the website.
To do that we will go through a free VPN service that your ISP cannot block.
Leave your computer set to the Google DNS servers, then choose
any free VPN service that you like from the list in
the article
[Best Free VPN](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-vpn.htm)
which also contains reviews.
Choose one that has good information of how to use it,
or ask here for help.

If this works, then your ISP is blocking that website and you should complain
loudly. You may need to convince them that this website is legitimate.
You can continue using the VPN as a workaround,
if its performance is good enough, or find a
[commercial one](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-vpn-services.htm).

The only good solution if your ISP does not fix the problem,
is to change the ISP,
that is if this website is important to you and you use it a lot.

Comment: Dear harrymc, I'm glad to say I tried step 2 that seems to best fit my needs and it seems to work. Just one thing I missed in the answer: `Assuming your router is connected by cable`. I assume you meant to the fact I connect the router itself to what I can generally call a "communication socket" and not to the fact I could use Ethernet. Than yes. I generally surf wireless but could use Ethernet instead.

Comment: BTW I see you have 229K rep points and RT Security that also helped me has 11... Is it okay I'll give him the bounty so we would give him a warm welcome?

Comment: Yes, I should have written "wired" rather than "cable". The bounty should usually go to the answer that solved your problem, but it's your reputation so it's your decision.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to where it took a long time for browsers to connect after the cache was flushed.

You might need to [disable Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol (WPAD)](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/disable-wpad-your-pc-so-your-https-traffic-wont-be-vulnerable-latest-ssl-attack-0172499/).

This could be done simply this way:

`Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy` and switch Automatically detect settings to **Off**.

Comment: @Run5k do you think it's safe?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It is simply an option built into the Windows 10 settings interface, so there really isn’t anything “unsafe” about it.

Comment: I turned it off and flushed all cache but I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is your home router based upon the “nslookup” response.

For troubleshooting I’d firsty try to see if you can ping the IP address of the web server in command prompt, followed by trying to ping the domain name of the website.

If you get a reply from pinging the IP and not the domain name it is likely the issue is DNS related (which is what im assuming from the nslookup results)

If that is the case I’d suggest using “ipconfig /all” in command prompt to establish what name servers your device is using. (Once again I’m assuming it is likely to use a local address that is associated to your router)

If that is the case change your network adapters settings whether its the wired or wireless one and manually change your DNS settings to use googles DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

This should help if you get stuck: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

If that resolves the issue I’d suggest logging on to your router and changing the routers DNS servers to Google’s as well.

Fingers Crossed for you!

Comment: Indeed I get a reply in `ping TARGET_DOMAIN` (question edited). I should indeed change my router's DNS (not sure what that means) to Google's DNS, I should read an article by Google on that and then do that on the router's control panel software.

Answer (score 0):

### If I understand the issue correctly:

You're trying to connect to your site on a remote server hosted by someone else

You've tried the following combinations:

- Windows 10, on your network, multiple browsers = **fail**
- iPhone, on your network, multiple browsers = **fail**
- Windows 10, on unsecured neighbor network, any browser = **success**
- iPhone, on unsecured neighbor network, any browser = **success**

In the failed environments, you've tried flushing DNS to no avail

At one point, it seemed to work, for one site, when you were able to get the Windows Network troubleshooter to assist with your supposed proxy settings

So, you've already ruled out the site, browser, and device:

- that the site is down
- that your browsers have a page caching issue
- that your devices have a dns cache issue
- that your browsers have a settings issue

### What's left

Really, the only thing that's left is your network.  So, there's your ISP, your modem, your router, your device.

- I presume that, connected to your network, you can see other pages, but you should double check.  After all, the first line in the troubleshooting guide is to make sure that it's plugged in :)
- Exclude your router and see if it works.  I know it's probably a PITA, but set up a wired connection directly to your modem.  Even if you have a wifi-enabled modem, this still excludes possible wifi issues.

  - If it works, then you can blame your router/wifi: this becomes a "it's your fault, you gotta fix it" problem. Try connecting directly to your router since you've got the cord out.

    - If it still works, it's something to do with your wifi configuration.
    - Whether it works or not, it's easiest to just factory reset your router and change one setting at a time back the way it was before, until you find the culprit.  Do yourself a favor and take some screenshots before you do the reset.  A pin reset works better than one from the router's page for many devices for some reason.
  - If it still doesn't work, something's going on with your ISP: they'll make you restart your modem every which way, and maybe try putting your modem back to factory settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do it.

1. There can be DNS issue. Either use Google Public DNS or CloudFlare DNS. This will more likely to resolve your issue.

But If problem still exists:

2. Go to https://whatismyip.live and copy your IP address and see if your IP is blocked by your server or hosting company. Give your IP to your hosting company or server company so that they can investigate any issue from their side.